# New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Property'. Powershell 2.0 Windows 2008

Tags: windows, powershell, window

I'm using this code in 2012 server but unable to run in windows 2008, i'm new to powershell script which tried to search online but unable to find an answer.

The error come from -property, which i tried -properties and pipe before -property also can't.

```
$OS = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object Caption,Version,ServicePackMajorVersion,OSArchitecture,CSName,WindowsDirectory
$HostName = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
$TargetPath = Get-Location
$ExportPath = $TargetPath.Path + "\" + $HostName + "_" + $OS.Caption + ".csv"
$UserAccount = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'"
$NetworkLoginProfile = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkLoginProfile
$GroupUser = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_GroupUser

if (Test-Path $ExportPath) 
{
    Remove-Item $ExportPath
}

Foreach($Account in $UserAccount){

    $Description = $Account.Description
    $Description = $Description.replace("`r`n","_")
    $Description = $Description.TrimEnd()

    $Profile = @{
        HostName = $HostName
        Domain = $Account.Domain    
        LocalAccount = $Account.LocalAccount    
        SID = $Account.SID  
        Name = $Account.Name    
        Caption = $Account.Caption  
        Status = $Account.Status    
        Disabled = $Account.Disabled    
        Lockout = $Account.Lockout
        FullName = $Account.FullName    
        Description = $Description  
        AccountType = $Account.AccountType  
        PasswordRequired = $Account.PasswordRequired    
        PasswordExpires = $Account.PasswordExpires  
        PasswordChangeable = $Account.PasswordChangeable    
        NumberOfLogons = ""
        LastLogon = ""
        UserComment = ""
        UserId = ""
        UserType = ""
        Workstations = ""
        BadPasswordCount = ""
        GroupMemberShip = ""
    }

    Foreach ($NetworkProfile in $NetworkLoginProfile)
    {
        If ($Account.Caption -eq $NetworkProfile.Name)
        {
            $Profile.NumberOfLogons = $NetworkProfile.NumberOfLogons
            $Profile.LastLogon = $NetworkProfile.LastLogon
            $Profile.UserComment = $NetworkProfile.UserComment
            $Profile.UserID = $NetworkProfile.UserId
            $Profile.UserType = $NetworkProfile.UserType
            $Profile.Workstations = $NetworkProfile.Workstations
            $Profile.BadPasswordCount = $NetworkProfile.BadPasswordCount
        }
    }

    $Groups = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    Foreach ($User in $GroupUser)
    {

        $PartComponent = $User.PartComponent

        $Index1 = $PartComponent.indexOf("Name=")
        $MemberName = $PartComponent.substring($Index1)
        $MemberName = $MemberName.substring(6)
        $MemberName = $MemberName.subString(0, $MemberName.indexOf("`""))

        $Index2 = $PartComponent.indexOf("Domain=")
        $MemberDomain = $PartComponent.subString($Index2)
        $MemberDomain = $MemberDomain.substring(8)
        $MemberDomain = $MemberDomain.substring(0, $MemberDomain.indexOf("`""))

        if (($MemberDomain -eq $Account.Domain) -and ($MemberName -eq $Account.Name))
        {
            $GroupComponent = $User.GroupComponent

            $Index3 = $GroupComponent.indexOf("Name=")
            $MemberGroup = $GroupComponent.substring($Index3)
            $MemberGroup = $MemberGroup.substring(6)
            $MemberGroup = $MemberGroup.subString(0, $MemberGroup.indexOf("`""))

            if($MemberGroup)
            {
                $Groups.Add($MemberGroup)
            }
        }
    }

    $count = 0

    Foreach ($Group in $Groups)
    {
        $count++

        if($count -lt $Groups.Count){
            $Profile.GroupMemberShip += $Group + '|'
        }
        else{
            $Profile.GroupMemberShip += $Group
        }      
    }      

    $Csv = New-Object psobject -Property $Profile
    $Csv | Select-Object -Property Hostname,Domain,LocalAccount,SID,Name,Caption,Status,Disabled,Lockout,FullName,Description,AccountType,PasswordRequired,PasswordExpires,PasswordChangeable,NumberOfLogons,LastLogon,UserComment,UserId,UserType,Workstations,BadPasswordCount,GroupMemberShip | Export-Csv $ExportPath -Append -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Error I receive:

[image]

Comment: What version of PowerShell your are running on 2012 and 2008? `$PSVersionTable`

Comment: Try explicitly specifying the first parameter name: `New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $profile`

Comment: @Mike type in and nothing came out, i think it is 1.0?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen tried still the same error.

Comment: Default versions: 2008 = PS v1.0 / 2008 R2 = v2.0 / 2012 = v3.0 / 2012 R2 = v4.0 ..... I think you have to update PS on Server 2008

Comment: Don't use `$Profile` as variable name because it is an [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#profile) in Powershell.

Comment: PLEASE do not post pics of text - be it code, errors, or data. why force others to work at reading your image when you already have the text?

Comment: @dragkin - the MSDocs site only lists back to ps3, so i looked for other docs ... and every ps2 example `New-Object` lacks the `-Property` parameter. it may not be there in ps2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's no longer supported, it's tough to find documentation this far back, but [I found mention of](https://9to5it.com/using-psobject-store-data-powershell/) `New-Object -Property` being used in Windows Powershell 2.0. In the comments under your question, you state that you are running Powershell 1.0. I am fairly confident that `-Property` did not exist on `New-Object` in v1.0, so you likely need to update your Windows Management Framework to get Powershell 2.0 or later.

Note that 2.0 is no longer supported so I would recommend going with a more recent verison of `Windows Powershell`, at least 4.0 if not 5.1. If you can, `Powershell Core` (v6) would give you the most modern Powershell experience, and will work with most `Windows Powershell` cmdlets on Windows systems if you install the `WindowsCompatibility` PowerShell module.